# How to draw SVG from XML Structure file?

Tags: pdftex, svg, xml

I extracted the XML description of a Chart from a Word Document. It is about 500 lines of code so I will not append it.

How can I draw the SVG for the XML file in Latex ?

Comment: Tikz can, but you probably have to manually extract some of the data from the xml file. Also note that depending what he chart is, it might be a lot easier to just recreate it in tikz

Comment: @daleif TikZ *can't*.  It can only draw SVG paths.

Comment: @HenriMenke so what exactly is in those XML files the OP is mentioning?

Comment: @daleif Paths encoded in XML object, e.g. `<circle ... />`, which TikZ can't parse.  TikZ can only parse the `d` part of a path like `<path d="M39 0h77v20H39z"/>`.

Comment: Those are mostly the SVG files I've dealt with, and they work just fine.

Comment: Is it possible to just export a one page Word document containing the chart to a pdf (which would build it to a svg) and then embedd that pdf into my latex document instead of the chart itself?

Comment: @Baumrinde there are many ways to extract a chart from word but unless it specifically uses the letters SVG it will not be one. A pdf from word is often an inferior jpg image wrapped up in a pdf heading. If the XML is designed to be read as VRML/SVG then that would be great but unless we have a copy of your unknown variant of word how can we guess the quality of its import/export contents

Comment: here is typical xml header of a Debian svg logo see how it identifies as both xml and svg <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 10.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 3.0.0 Build 77)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd" [